# When is the latest Calibre 3 going to be available in Ubuntu 16.04 in Software Center?

Tags: 16.04, ebooks, calibre

The current version which is 2.55.0 is not working for me and does not support my Pocketbook Inkpad 3 ebook reader and other ways of installation are too complicated for me.

Comment: SHort answer is, "as soon as the devs build it as a snap and put it in the snappy store." Longer answer is https://askubuntu.com/q/151283

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the fact that we can not change release policy inside Ubuntu, you probably will not get it from official Ubuntu *xenial* repositories.

But you can use one of the following methods to install the software:

1. You can try to install calibre from [Jonathon F's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/calibre).

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/calibre
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install calibre
   ```

   This will install v3.25 [which is newer than v3.21 from Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=calibre).

   It looks great:

   [image: Calibre v.3.21]
2. Also can try to download latest version from official site:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   https://download.calibre-ebook.com/3.26.1/calibre-3.26.1-x86_64.txz
   tar -xf calibre-3.26.1-x86_64.txz
   ```

   and launch it from here with

   ```
   ./calibre
   ```
3. Other possibility is a [Snap package](https://snapcraft.io/).

   Currently no calibre snap-package exist. Calibre has very beautiful interface, but Snap currently ignores theming, so it will not look pretty.

   And I have doubts about the functionality of this option. Snap-version may not have access to USB-memory of the ebook-reader because of missed [`removable-media` plug/interface](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034030/66509).

   Also about Snap version I can cite [*Eli Schwartz (eschwartz)*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1707517/comments/1) from ["
   feature request - package calibre as snap app" bug-report 1707517 from 2017-07-30 at launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1707517):

   > There is already a cross-distro tarball that works without snap.
   >
   > Also IMHO snap is still a disaster and I'm very grateful Kovid doesn't
   >   use it. He's already rejected snap multiple times
   >
   > https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux
   >
   > duplicate [1699620](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1699620)

Comment: You might also that the answer to when is "never." :)

Comment: That was my point exactly ;) It's a either a ppa if there is one, compile from source, or install project binaries if they exist. It's a good answer, but I still think you should explain that apart from (possibly) backporting security updates, the version next will never be in the 16.04 repos

Comment: +1 for answering the question first with a practical solution, and finding the PPA and improving the answer since then.

Comment: The answer is not never. Snap packages show up in software center, and one could ship newer calibre as a snap if one so wanted.

Comment: Snap != official xenial repository, right, @dobey? And "Never" answer is below, so not mine. I completely can't understand what you guys want...

Comment: And the question wasn't about "official xenial repository." The question is "when will it show up in software center?" However, the snap store is an officially supported repository of software, and which shows up in _Ubuntu Software_ by default.

Comment: Please post link to Snap now! Moreover Snap-version may not have access to USB-memory of the ebook-reader because of sandbox.

Comment: There is no snap version currently, afaik. However, there is nothing preventing anyone from uploading a snap to the store, unlike the release policy for the deb package repositories.

Comment: @dobey Cited comment from calibre developers about Snap (for your information).

Comment: @N0rbert if I download it from the official site, will it get automatically updated to the latest version later?

Comment: @geras No, txz-version will not be updated. The PPA solution seems the most user-friendly for me. It will update the package on next `apt-get upgrade` or by Software Updater (of coarse if JonathonF will build new package).

Comment: There is a snap interface for accessing storage devices.

Comment: @dobey "There is a snap interface for accessing storage devices" - false, see [this question as an illustration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap).

Comment: See https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Interfaces

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to query the snap store for apps that support a specific interface.

Comment: @N0rbert and which source would you say is safer or more trusted? JonathonF's  PPA or the official site?

Comment: If you ask me, I trust JonathonF as I use Firefox ESR from his PPA. He simple backported package and launchpad compiled source package. You can decide about Calibre youself.

Answer (score 2):

## The answer is "never" (Or One Day...)

Ubuntu 16.04 was released 2 years ago. The software center keeps apps that are tested to be stable and works well with that version.

The software center of a more recent version of Ubuntu, such as 18.04, which came out last week, have a more recent version of Calibre 3.21.0.

You may want to upgrade your Ubuntu to 18.04 in about 6 or 7 month's time when the upgrade option will appear in your Ubuntu 16.04 system. At the time of the upgrade, your Calebre will be updated to version 3.21. It will remain at that version until you upgrade Ubuntu again.

**Or One Day...**

The makers of Calibre (or someone else) may decide to make their software [available as a snap package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)) to Ubuntu. In that case, version 3 or newer may be available to Ubuntu 16.04. The nature of snap package is such that it will get automatically updated to the newest version irrespective of the version of Ubuntu.

## Use a PPA until then

A Personal Package Archive (PPA) is a software repository for uploading source packages to be built and published as an Advanced Packaging Tool (APT) repository by Launchpad. As the name implies, these are personal, and not officially supported by Ubuntu. See [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

If you want to use the PPA and get Clibre 3.21 running in Ubuntu 16.04, then follow [N0rbert's](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) answer and open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/calibre
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Or if Calibre is already installed replace the last command with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the first command, you will be prompted for your password. **When you type the password in the terminal, nothing will show, and the cursor will not move. This is normal.** Just type the password blindly and hit enter. In the subsequent times you won't be asked for the password.

Hope this helps

Comment: The answer is not never. Snap packages show up in software center, and one could ship newer calibre as a snap if one so wanted.

Comment: Thanks @dobey for reminding me of Snap packages. I have edit my answer.